# Kotlin - How to query list of generic KClass Model in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

```
fun getListSize(clazz: KClass<*>) {

        val session = hibernate.openSession()

        val cb = session.criteriaBuilder

        val criteria = cb.createQuery(clazz.java)
        val root = criteria.from(clazz.java)
        criteria.select(root)


        val query = session.createQuery(criteria)
        return query.resultList.size

    }
```

I am getting an error on the line `criteria.select(root)` stating: `Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Root<out Any!>! but Selection<out Nothing!>! was expected`

It works perfectly fine with the class is specified such as `Country::class.java` but otherwise fails.

Comment: You mean that all is perfect when `criteria.from(Country::class.java)` is used?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko That is correct. When I replace all instances of clazz.java with a class that exists and is an entity, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun <T : Any> getListSize(clazz: KClass<T>) {

        val session = hibernate.openSession()

        val cb = session.criteriaBuilder

        val criteria = cb.createQuery(clazz.java)
        val root = criteria.from(clazz.java)
        criteria.select(root)


        val query = session.createQuery(criteria)
        return query.resultList.size

    }
```

The following changes to the function allowed the `criteria.select(root)` to work.

Adding `<T : Any>` to the function and passing the `T` as the type into KClass worked for me.